# infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p$ divides $a_{1}^k+a_{2}^k+...+a_{n}^k$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Consider the positive integers $a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{n}$, not all identical ($n>1$).
Prove that there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p$ divides $a_{1}^k+a_{2}^k+...+a_{n}^k$ for some positive integer $k$.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, we can assume that $\gcd(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=1$.

Assume, by contradiction, that the set of prime divisors of the numbers
$$ q(k) = a_1^k+\ldots+a_n^k $$
is finite, $\mathcal{P}=\{p_1,\ldots,p_m\}$.

By the [Van der Waerden's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waerden%27s_theorem), there exist $a,b\in\mathbb{N}^*$ and $i\in[1,m]$ such that:
$$\forall s\in\left[0,n+1\right],\qquad q(a+bs)\equiv 0\pmod{p_i} \tag{1}$$
but
$$q_s = q(a+bs)$$
is an integer sequence that satisfies an homogeneous recurrence relation with constant coefficients. Since the degree of the characteristic polynomial is $n$ but $q_s\equiv 0\pmod{p_i}$ for $n+2$ consecutive values of $s$, $a_j\equiv 0\pmod{p_i}$ for every $j\in[1,n]$.

However, this contradicts the initial assumption $\gcd(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=1$.

Comment: Thanks Jack D'Aurizio, very nice idea.  Actually I have a question: consider $a_1=3,a_2=5$. Note that in this case $q(k)=3^k+5^k$. We have $q(k)\equiv 0\pmod{2}$ for all $k$ and $a_1,a_2\equiv 1\pmod{2}$. Doesn't this invalidate your following argument?  

'_Since the degree of the characteristic polynomial is $n$ but $q_s\equiv 0\pmod{p_i}$ for $n+2$ consecutive values of $s$, $a_j\equiv 0\pmod{p_i}$ for every $j\in[1,n]$._'